# How can I run the fdnadist command from the EMBOSS package?

Tags: sequence-analysis, phylogenetics, software-installation, emboss

My operating system is Mac OS X.

I would like to compute DNA distances between different sequences. For this, the dnadist package from the Phylip software would be good but hard to automate. [EMBOSS](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/release/6.0/embassy/phylipnew/fdnadist.html) seems to have an fdnadist command for this. I have installed emboss version 6.6.0 from the bioconda package but if I type `fdnadist`, the command is not found. How can I use `dnadist` or `fdnadist` on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find `emboss` packages type `wossname`, then hit enter twice.  You will see all the programs.  There is one called `distmat`.  Then do `tfm distmat`, to get `the fkn manual` for `distmat`.

Answer (score 2):

I found fdnadist in embassy-phylip package https://anaconda.org/bioconda/embassy-phylip